# In bootstrap 4 beta, how to right align last nav item?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this simple nav with three nav-items in bootstrap 4, beta:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link test1" data-toggle="pill" href="#test1" aria-expanded="false">Test1</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link test1" data-toggle="pill" href="#test2" aria-expanded="false">Test2</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link test3" data-toggle="pill" href="#test3" aria-expanded="false">Test3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I would like, is for the nav-item called *Test3* to be right aligned inside the ul.

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/10/).

How can I do this?

Comment: Already been answered, use `ml-auto` https://www.codeply.com/go/Og3u9kyQHS

Comment: @ZimSystem .... or reset margin-left:auto to the li:last-child  (css tag selected too )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by adding `ml-auto` to the last item. That sets the left margin to `auto`, which means it will take the maximum available space as margin, so it will jump to right.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link test1" data-toggle="pill" href="#test1" aria-expanded="false">Test1</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link test1" data-toggle="pill" href="#test2" aria-expanded="false">Test2</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-link test3" data-toggle="pill" href="#test3" aria-expanded="false">Test3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's bad for accessibility (and semantic structure in general) to break one item out of a list. Can you accomplish this without doing so?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer.

Comment: I think the `w-100` is unnecessary

Comment: @ZimSystem You're right, thanks for pointing that out! :) I removed it. (For some reason it seemed necessary when I first wrote the code.)